# Logging NHibernate Info from unit-testing project with Resharper

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, nunit, resharper

I'm trying to capture NHibernate logging information from a unit testing project using NUnit & ReSharper.  The test project is configured as a Class Library and it has it's own App.Config file.  I know the App.Config file is correct because if I use it in a console application, I see all the NHibernate logging.  When this App.Config file is placed in a unit testing project, Log4Net mysteriously stops working.

I've also played around with initializing Log4Net in the test project itself. I've tried adding `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]` to the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  I've also tried calling...

```
[SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

...in the test fixture.  Nothing works.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with Resharper. I'm guessing that you are using the Resharper test runner, but that is simply using NUnit to do the actual test execution. I would recommend removing the resharper tag, and the name from the question. Glad you figured out what your problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Okay, so the first problem is Log4Net was silently failing because the directory I was writing to under Win7 was not accessible.  I changed the directory in the Log4Net Appender to just .\nhibernate.log which will write it to the default Debug directory.

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <file value=".\nhibernate.log"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <conversionPattern value="%d{HH:mm:ss.fff} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Also, I had to still initialize Log4Net in the test fixture like the following.

```
[SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I just use `log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();` which logs to the console. No additional config or files required.